# Cakephp 3 - How to use sortWhiteList for belongsToMany associations?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.x

I mimicked the bookmarker tutorial to setup the basic files/logic needed to have tags associated to my products, but I can't get the 'sortWhiteList' functionality to work with the belongsToMany association. Any thoughts?

The model(entity and table) are working as the tags get saved.

The following is just one way I have tried it. I have tried many different scenarios, looking at the documentation, searching online, but I can't figure it out. Any help is much appreciated.

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->paginate = [
        'sortWhitelist' => [
            'Products.title',
            'Products.affiliate_link',
            'Products.msrp',
            'Products.sale_price',
            'Products.Tags.name',
        ],
        'contain' => ['Tags'],
        'limit'   => 48,
        'order'   => ['Products.title' => 'asc']
    ];
    $products = $this->Products->find();
    $this->set('products', $this->paginate($products));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['products']);
}
```

View:

```
    <ul class="side-nav no-bullet">
        <li><h3><?= __('Sort') ?></h3></li>
        <li><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Products.title', 'Title') ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Products.msrp', 'Retail Price') ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Products.sale_price', 'Sale Price') ?></li>
        <li><?= $this->Paginator->sort('Products.Tags.name', 'Tag Name') ?></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: How would you expect this to work anyways? The tags are groups, ie you possibly have multiple tags per product, how would the system decide which single tag of a group to pick, and use for sorting?

Comment: @ndm I see what you mean. One possibility could be: say you have two tags, books and videos. Any products that have the tag books would come first, even if they were tagged with videos as well.

Comment: Well, you'd need an additional column to that, otherwise the order of those "grouped" records that have the `books` tag, and those don't have the `books` tag, would be unpredictable. In any case you'll need custom logic to handle this, the paginator component is not able to do this kind of stuff for you.